# previous month SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation

I just want a column showing the previous month (from [today]). I didn't get [Ryan's solution](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2009/11/howto-filter-items-current-calendar-month-view-sharepoint/comment-page-4/#comments):

calculated column

```
=DATE(YEAR([Created]), MONTH([Created])+1, 1)
```

> Syntax error

Could somebody please explain his thoughts and doings.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "," by ";"

```
=DATE(YEAR(Created);MONTH(Created)+1;1)
```

Comment: thanks, that worked now. Still working on the solution though.